# How to color words in codemirror with condition?

Tags: javascript, css, codemirror

I build my own language on codemirror , I have array contain the name of my classes and I have also temp array (when I type name of class then I loaded the fields of this class in temp array)

For example, if I have two classes:

The name of first class is **Data** and it's fields are:

`fname`,
`lname`,
`age`

The name of second class is **info** and its fields are:

`mother`,
`father`

when I type on codemirror **Data** then the temp array contain (`fname`,`lname`,`data`)
when I type on codemirror **info** then the temp array contain (`mother`,`father`)

### What I want

To color the fields in specific color only if it comes after the name of own class (i.e when I type on codemirror `Data.fname` I want to color the word **fname** in blue color But when I type on codemirror `info.fname` I did not want to color the word **fname** in blue color because (**fname** not contain in the class "info"))

### What I try

```
CodeMirror.defineMode("mymode", function() {    
    return {
        token: function(stream,state) {
            for (var i = 0; i <ClassName.length ; i++) {
                if (stream.match(ClassName[i]) ) {
                    return "style1";
                }                   
            }
            for (var i = 0; i <temp.length ; i++) {
                if (stream.match(temp[i]) ) {
                    return "style2";
                }                   
            }                   
    };        
});
```

### My problem in my try

the contain of array **temp** is change when I type the name of class on codemirror ... so what happen is :
when I type on codemirror `Data.fname` then the word **fname** color in blue But if I type on codemirror `Data.fname  info.mother` (Before I type info.mother the word **fname** color in blue because it is contain in temp array (`fname`,`lname`,`data`), but after I type **info.mother** the contain of temp array is change to (`mother`,`father`) ) so the the color of **fname** became black

**this picture show you the execute **

[here the word "fname" color in blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWC2m.png)

[here the color of word "fname" change and became black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF2U7.png)

I knew my problem because the contain of array temp is change... But I can't find way to solve it... so any help?

Comment: any body can help :(

Comment: how are you loading fields in `temp` array?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into various language [modes](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/tree/master/mode) available in codemirror's source (like python, javascript) etc. You need to know about tokenisation, which is the basis of any language mode implementation. Also have a look at codemirror's [themes](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/tree/master/theme), so that your implementation can support multiple themes for your language.